# How to store arabic names into `mysql DB`

Tags: php, mysql

How to store **Arabic** usernames into `mysql` ? . I am **using charset="latin" for showing Arabic names**.But it print in mysql is **???????** marks. So i did't get any idea about this please suggest me what to do?.

```
<?php
header('content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('noorbiz');
mysql_query("set names utf8");
list($id,$name)=mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM poll_categories'));
echo $name;
?>


This is Database Table:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `poll_categories` (
  `category_id` tinyint(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `category_name` varchar(50) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `poll_categories` (`category_id`, `category_name`) VALUES
(1, 'لبنان يا بلد صغير بالقلب كبير');
```

If Run above code it shows **??????** Marks in mysql> But I want store the same formt of **Arabic words**.

[image]

Comment: You probably have to use utf8 charset, since there are no arabic characters in "latin"

Comment: I have tried utf8 also but i get the above the problem please help me @Sergio Tulentsev

Comment: It's not working i will send my code once again If see once where i did mistake @Sergio Tulentsev

Comment: <?php
header('content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('testhlg');
mysql_query("set names utf8");
mysql_query("set character_set 'utf8'");
list($id,$name)=mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM poll_categories'));
echo $name;
?> @Sergio Tulentsev

Comment: Must be some problems on the PHP side. Mysql handles this just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e38381/1/0

Comment: Is it possible to store user names in mysql in Arabic format @Sergio Tulentsev

Comment: @user3214030 have you tried displaying the result in a browser? Does your terminal supports UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Arabic tries this

1. set MySQL charset: `UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)`
2. Set MySQL connection collation: `utf8_general_ci`
3. Set database and table collations are set to:`utf8_general_ci
   orutf8_unicode_ci`

   mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

   ```
   mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
   ```

http://www.adviesenzo.nl/examples/php_mysql_charset_fix/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `utf8_general_ci` and you should also use this

```
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
mysql_query("set character_set 'utf8'");
```

after you connect to the database. By the way mysql_* is deprecated, you should use mysqli_*.

Comment: Some links would improve this answer.